# What is "USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY" in rubyGems env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Here's my RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.2
- RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-darwin14]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/wh026399/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
- **USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY**: /Users/wh026399/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/wh026399/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/wh026399/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/wh026399/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-14
- GEM PATHS:

  - /Users/wh026399/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
  - /Users/wh026399/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global

I was wondering what "USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY" is. why it not point to gems under folder .rvm but .gem instead? Also, why is it using 2.2.0 which is a ruby version I didn't install?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The User Installation Directory variable for RubyGems is the directory where gems will be installed when using the `--user-install` flag, which is a directory immediately within your home directory.

The User Installation Directory has always existed, but it was recently made more visible via [pull 1343](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/1343).

Comment: I installed ruby via rvm command "rvm install 2.2.2". why did it create ruby/2.2.0 under .gem folder?

Comment: No idea, but that's a second question, isn't it?

Comment: @wei Did you find that second question out? Ended up here because of another issue but I think they are related!