# Why doesn't 'USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY' match with the Ruby version?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

This question was the second part of "[What is "USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY" in rubyGems env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215396/what-is-user-installation-directory-in-rubygems-env)" but finally it wasn't answered.

Now I'm wondering why in my case `'USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` does not mach with the Ruby version. And another question is what option `bundle install` uses by default, maybe `--user-install`?

`rvm list`:

```
 * ruby-2.5.0 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.0-preview1 [ x86_64 ]
```

`gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ivan/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  ...
```

Comment: Please, don't post photographs of text. Post text. This is a programming website, not a photography website. We want to read, and probably copy&paste, what you post, not critique its use of perspective of color.

Comment: Sorry. You`re totally right

Comment: "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)" also, see "[ask]". You're asking two separate and unrelated questions.

Answer (score 5):

The installation directory for Gems is based on the library compatibility version of Ruby. Since Ruby 2.5.1 is library-compatible with Ruby 2.5.0, its library compatibility version is still 2.5.0.