# rbenv wrong gem version in installation directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I want to use `ruby-2.4.1` in my application and installed `rbenv` and also installed 2.4.1 with it.

I can confirm that `ruby -v` prints out 2.4.1 is being used.

`gem env` leads to the following:

```
RubyGems Environment:
             - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.11
- RUBY VERSION: 2.4.1 (2017-03-22 patchlevel 111) [x86_64-darwin18]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/thementoria/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
- USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/thementoria/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/thementoria/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/thementoria/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/thementoria/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/thementoria/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
- x86_64-darwin-18
- GEM PATHS:
    - /Users/thementoria/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
- /Users/thementoria/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
    - :update_sources => true
- :verbose => true
- :backtrace => false
- :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
    - https://rubygems.org/
    - SHELL PATH:
    - /Users/thementoria/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin
- /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec
- /Users/thementoria/.rbenv/bin
- /Users/thementoria/.rbenv/shims
- /usr/local/bin
- /usr/bin
- /bin
     - /usr/sbin
- /sbin
     - /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

Note that my `USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`, `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` and `GEM PATHS` have `2.4.0` in it.

What causes this to happen?

In my `.bashrc` I have:

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @anothermh: How exactly would RVM solve the OP's problem, which is that the OP doesn't understand the difference between the Ruby Language Version and the Ruby Library Compatibility Version? Also, how is this a problem with rbenv?

Comment: Also, see [Why 'USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY' doesn't mach with ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52128611/2988)

Answer (score 0):

All is fine. Ruby assumes that all gems within a minor version are fully compatible.

This is probably based on a 20 year old decision which would allow you to transfer installed gems within patch versions of Rubies, by simply copying or symlinking them, without downloading them again. I doubt that the same decision would be made today.