# should ruby gem versions match main ruby version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I having real problems with Rails after brew updates and permission changes.

I am getting the following error and I'm wondering if the issue is because the difference in Ruby and gem versions in the path:

```
/Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:74: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000110
```

Could this be this issues for the faults?

Comment: did you try `rbenv rehash` ?

Comment: Hey, have just tried rbenv but thats doesnt seem to change anything

Comment: please add output of `gem env` to your question.  Also what command are you running to get the error?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52128611/2988. Unfortunately, it can't be closed as a duplicate because that other question doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer.

Comment: I faced it once and could not find out a way to fix but after uninstalling the ruby and reinstall it, everything was fine.